# XDG0008 xaml uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

does not find user control in namespace

everywhere, even on the book I bought, it says that to create a custom control I have to create a folder, add a user control, declare the namespace on the page and then I can use it. There are no other errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by creating a new project, creating the controls, and copying and pasting the controls code.
I probably unintentionally removed some files or settings or there was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you refer to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-22621#examples) to learn how to use UWP UserControl. You can directly create a UserControl resource without creating a folder.

You can use [`local:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping#local-and-common) to map to the UserControl. `local:` mapped to refer to the same namespace that's created to contain the `x:Class` attribute and code for all the XAML files.

```
 <Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl1/>
 </Grid>
```